# How to implement foreach loop in echo in php

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, echo

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> Country</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="countryId" name="countryId">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
      <?php
        if(!empty($country))
        {
          foreach ($country as $record)
          {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $record->id ?>"><?php echo $record->countryName ?></option>
              <?php
          }
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my trying (Not successful):

```
echo '
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>'.(($required<>'0')?'<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i>':"").' '.$friendlyName.'</label>
    <select '.(($readonly<>'0')?'readonly':"").' '.(($disabled<>'0')?'disabled':"").' class="form-control select2 '.$columnClass.'" id="'.$columnId.'" name="'.$columnName.'">
      <option value="0">Select Country</option>'.
        if(!empty($country))
        {
          foreach ($country as $record)
          {
              .'<option value="$record->id">$record->countryName</option>'.
          }
        }
    .'</select>
  </div>
</div>
';
```

When i run echo code it gives me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

How do I echo this block of html and php including foreach loop.

Comment: Don't `echo` it. Just have it outside of a PHP block (`<?php ... ?>`). The actual PHP within it is already surrounded by these tags.

Answer (score 0):

I tried other way:

```
$html = '
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>'.(($required<>'0')?'<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i>':"").' '.$friendlyName.'</label>
  <select '.(($readonly<>'0')?'readonly':"").' '.(($disabled<>'0')?'disabled':"").' class="form-control select2 '.$columnClass.'" id="'.$columnId.'" name="'.$columnName.'">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>';
      if(!empty($country))
      {
      foreach ($country as $record)
        {
          $html .= '<option value="'.$record->id.'">'.$record->countryName.'</option>';
        }
      }
$html .= '</select>
    </div>
  </div>
';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Hello. Did you read my comment above?

Comment: yes but I asked if there is any way to echo that all code.

Comment: `echo` is just sending stuff to the output. By having the HTML directly in the file, it does exactly the same thing (outputs it). There seems to be no point in using `echo` in your case, you could just paste it somewhere and get the same result.

Comment: alright okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing as string loop each item by using `<?php foreach():  ?>`

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> Country</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="countryId" name="countryId">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
      <?php if(!empty($country): ?>
          <?php foreach ($country as $record): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $record->id ?>">
               <?php echo $record->countryName ?>
            </option>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my all string is already in php i cant use php tag again

Comment: what do you mean? @Danial212k

Comment: i am echoing this code in loop

Comment: don't echo it as string try my solution.